# No compiling errors, execution on ADB fails

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app with google maps APIs. First time I ever see such an error. What it is? Seems like a "runtime" error

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person$AgeRange;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person$AgeRange;"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: Hard to say and these things are a pain to debug through. Are you importing the lib multiple times? Best I can suggest is to check your Gradle build and see what's going on since this generally means that there's a nameclash in your imports and/or your code.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up deleting .gradle folder and resyncing. Now it compiles without errors